# Set texture of a LHSprite that is loaded from LevelHelper

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, objective-c

How do i set the image/texture of an LHSprite that is loaded into xCode using levelHelper & spriteHelper?

I am using sprite sheets. So i tried to load the image the old fashioned way using CCSpriteFrameCache, but unfortunately it isnt recognizing the .pshs file :( Any Help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, I just added another animation which consists of 1 frame, then when i need it, i play the animation:

```
[mySprite stopAnimation]; //Stops CurrentAnimation
[mySprite prepareAnimationNamed:@"jumpAnimation" fromSHScene:@"Jungle"];
[mySprite playAnimation];
```